Kernel 6.8.11-amd64 Headers not being able to install
I am not able to install the linux-headers-6.8.11-amd64 kernel even after repeated trying. I tried several methods - sudo apt-get update, apt-get upgrade, apt-get dist-upgrade sudo dkms --configure linux-headers-amd64 sudo apt-get install linux-headers-amd64; but to no avail. In addition, the error the terminal shows is as follows:
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.8.11-amd64 (--configure):
installed linux-headers-6.8.11-amd64 package post-installation 
script subprocess returned error exit status 11
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-amd64:
linux-headers-amd64 depends on linux-headers-6.8.11-amd64 
(=   6.8.11-1kali2); however:
Package linux-headers-6.8.11-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-amd64 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-6.8.11-rt-amd64-dbg (6.8.11-1kali2) ...
Setting up linux-image-6.8.11-rt-amd64 (6.8.11-1kali2) ...
I: /initrd.img.old is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-6.8.11-rt-amd64
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.11-rt-amd64.
Sign command: /lib/modules/6.8.11-rt-amd64/build/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
Building module(s)....................(bad exit status: 2)
Failed command:
'make' all KVER=6.8.11-rt-amd64
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 
6.8.11-rt-amd64   (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8188fu/1.0/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.11-rt-amd64/x86_64 failed for rtl8188fu(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.8.11-rt-amd64 failed!

From the errors, I feel the wifi driver rtl8188fu is the one that creates trouble. But, it is the driver for the wifi adapter for my PC, and deleting it would mean no internet for me. So, how should I proceed. For information, I currently have linux-header uname -a version as 6.6.9. Rebooting will log me to the latest version Kali Linux 6.8.11, but without wifi drivers in the ifconfig, and without internet connection. For reference, here is first few lines of the content of the /var/lib/dkms/rtl8188fu/1.0/build/make.log file:
DKMS make.log for rtl8188fu-1.0 for kernel 
6.8.11-cloud-amd64 (x86_64)
Friday 12 July 2024 04:51:10 PM IST
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C 
/lib/modules/6.8.11- cloud-amd64/build 
M=/var/lib/dkms /rtl8188fu/1.0/build  modules
make[1]: Entering directory 
'/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.11-cloud-amd64'
CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8188fu/1.0/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8188fu/1.0/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:2225:4:     warning: no previous prototype for ‘_rtw_set_chplan_cmd’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
 2225 | u8 _rtw_set_chplan_cmd(_adapter *adapter,  
int  flags,       u8 chplan, const struct 
country_chplan  *country_ent, u8 swconfig)
  |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8188fu/1.0/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:2769:6:  warning: no previous prototype for ‘dynamic_chk_wk_hdl’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2769 | void dynamic_chk_wk_hdl(_adapter *padapter)
  |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8188fu/1.0/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:2963:6:   warning: no previous prototype for ‘rtw_dm_in_lps_hdl’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2963 | void rtw_dm_in_lps_hdl(_adapter*padapter)
  |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8188fu/1.0/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:3004:6: warning: no previous prototype for ‘rtw_lps_change_dtim_hdl’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
 3004 | void rtw_lps_change_dtim_hdl
(_adapter *padapter, u8 dtim)
  |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

For the full file, as it is very large, the link to open in Drive is here
Any hints?

We need to know for certain if your WiFi drivers are at fault, we can assist in finding a solution to that problem, but it will be difficult for us to prob a solution if your not certain that’s the problem. Probably should provide /var/lib/dkms/rtl8188fu/1.0/build/make.log

@Ramhound edited the post to include the desired file. Please check now.

I was able to solve the non updating/upgrading/dist0upgrading problem by getting rid/purging of the linux-headers-6.8.11-amd64 and their corollaries. To so this, I used the Synaptic package manager, available by using the apt-get install synaptic. The method using terminal and aptitude was not completely successful in my case. Some methods to purge unwanted header files can be found here.
By the way, the issue in OP was also pointed out in kali bugs. Hence, this link will also prove useful for those having similar problems.
